# Playing sound on my website

Tags: html, embed

I use a code to play background music on my website..

```
<embed src="1.wav" autostart="true" loop="true"
width="2" height="0">
</embed>
```

But this code does not play infinite looped music..
Once the sound track gets over it does no repeat..
What should i do to repeat the music again and again..

Comment: Please don't do this. Background music is annoying and very 90's.

Comment: None of your visitors want to hear that ....

Comment: But i want background music.. i am creating a cultural fest website.. and i have no hint how to do so..

Comment: If you _need_ to play music, use a player control that the user can start/stop.

Comment: Have a play button so visitors can decide if they want what they're already listening to interrupted.

Comment: So can you suggesst me some easy to implement but goodlooking music player.. jquery is fine for me..

Comment: @FREAKENGINEER I haven't used it, but [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/) looks like a good start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML5 solution is the Audio tag http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_audio.asp

This is the older solution: http://drayblog.gotdns.com/index.php/2009/05/13/html-embed-an-audio-clip-and-repeat-loop-it/

```
<EMBED SRC="/audio/media.mp3" AUTOSTART="true" HIDDEN="True" LOOP="True"/>
<NOEMBED>
    <object type="audio/mp3" data="http://www.domain.com/audio/media.mp3"><param name="src" value="http://www.domain.com/audio/media.mp3"></param><param name="autostart" value="true"></param><param name="hidden" value="True"></param><param name="loop" value="true"></param>
    </object>
</NOEMBED>
```

Comment: I'd like to vote you up, but that link is w3schools.  I've been lead to believe that I will die a horrible death for using or suggesting someone use w3schools.

Comment: @cadrell0 - overcoming willful ignorance is always difficult. I don't know what evidence or facts you have for believing that, in fact, I'm really hoping you're just joking.

Comment: They may have gotten a little better lately, but check out http://w3fools.com/ ...

Comment: @jrummell - all the examples given are reasonable quibbles and the fact that it usurps the W3C name without affiliation is shady at best. However, for referencing an HTML tag, attributes and maybe an example, it's information is accurate. This leads me to the conclusion that I just don't have the energy to give a damn about the e-peen war between web documentation sites, or the infallibility of the sporadic bits of editorial opinion that show up on those sites. If the bits of information that "I" need (or am referencing) from a site are accurate then that's where the buck stops with me.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I have found to work the best... Just replace the 'yoursounds' with the actual file name of your chosing.

```
<audio autoplay loop controls>
    <source src="yoursound.ogg">
    <source src="yoursound.mp3">
</audio>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of loop='true' try with loop='infinite' as below

```
<embed src="1.wav" autostart="true" loop="infinite"
width="2" height="0">
</embed>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using the audio tag instead:

```
<audio autoplay loop>
    <source src="sound.ogg">
    <source src="sound.mp3"> 
</audio>
```

You need to use both mp3 and ogg files to be able to play your sound correctly in all browsers. <del>Firefox for instance does not support mp3 files.</del> Also using .wav is on websites is severely frowned upon due to its size.

Comment: Or add controls to the opening audio tag to display a simple control element the user can interact with

Answer (score 0):

Try [jPlayer](http://jplayer.org/). It's an html5 media player that will fallback on flash. Here's an example from one of the demos:

```
$("#jquery_jplayer_1").jPlayer({
    ready: function () {
        $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
            m4a:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/m4a/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.m4a",
            oga:"http://www.jplayer.org/audio/ogg/TSP-01-Cro_magnon_man.ogg"
        });
    },
    swfPath: "../js",
    solution: "flash, html",
    supplied: "m4a, oga",
    wmode: "window"
});

<div id="jquery_jplayer_1" class="jp-jplayer"></div>
```

http://jplayer.org/latest/demo-01-solution-flash-html/

Answer (score 0):

```
<audio hidden="true" autoplay loop controls>
    <source src="source.mp3">
</audio>
```

it will works fine as you want...